# Security support time for OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, support-cycle

If I install OpenBSD 4.9, when will I have to upgrade to 5.0? When will the 4.9 release no longer be supported by the OBSD teams?

Comment: on http://www.openbsd.org/errata47.html it says: 013: SECURITY FIX: February 16, 2011 and http://www.openbsd.org/48.html says: Released Nov 1, 2010 - so I have to upgrade my 4.9 when 5.1 comes out? So in short the version support for OpenBSD is at least 1 year for a given version?

Comment: Probably not the best place to ask this.  OpenBSD releases new major version every six months, if it helps you in any way, so 5.0 is due somewhere this fall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The security support for a given version in OpenBSD is 1 year.

From the [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#Flavors):

> You will also note that in the above example, the 4.6-stable branch came to an end with 4.8-release, and the 4.7-stable branch came to an end with 4.9-release -- old releases are typically supported up to two releases back.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to join critical OpenBSD mailing lists to be made aware of upgrades and fixes.

http://www.openbsd.org/mail.html